# Using AWK to Retrieve an Error in a Cryptic Log File

Tags: awk, aix

I need to grab an occurrence of error for the current time, ignoring early occurrences.  The problem is the date is few lines above (not on the same line as error code).  How do I return the information from

```
***begin ibmdb error message***
```

which has the date & time to equate that to current time, and include all of this error log data:

```
*** begin ibmdb error message ***
Sun Dec 18 21:50:57 2016 - program 'execjob', User 'OSID:root', RMId 'root'  Driver Version '9.0.1.14.865 2015-01-20 04:00:00'
DELETEDBREC() error on file 'USERRPT' in 'GEN'

DeleteSqlRec(lawson."USERRPT", 1)
DB2 FATAL ERROR for SQLExecute - Code: 40001/-911
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0911N  The current transaction has been rolled
back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".  SQLSTATE=40001
```

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="begin ibmdb error message"}`  captures the beginning - how do I encapsulate the ending with - `Reason code "68"`

Comment: AWK is record-oriented. If you can't define the record, append lines to a variable from your starting pattern until you hit `Reason code "68"`.

Comment: I see - so the output I gave as an example would be multiple records and AWK can not retrieve the sections as one record.

Comment: Some awks can use regular expressions to split records, and some can't. [GNU awk certainly can.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html) It's also not obvious from your question whether other records are interspersed. So appending lines is usually a safe fallback. YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FS** tells awk that the fields on your line will be separated by 'begin ibmdb error message'

You probably want to do something like

```
awk '/begin ibmdb error message/,/Reason code "68"/'
```

Comment: I actually saw your answer before I wrote mine. But I did not understand your answer. :-)

Comment: With the difference that I answered the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I have started from the time point just for testing, instead of `begin ibmdb error message` since i thought might be more sections starting with the same text.

```
$ awk '/21:50/,/Reason code "68"/' file11
Sun Dec 18 21:50:57 2016 - program 'execjob', User 'OSID:root', RMId 'root'  Driver Version '9.0.1.14.865 2015-01-20 04:00:00'
DELETEDBREC() error on file 'USERRPT' in 'GEN'

DeleteSqlRec(lawson."USERRPT", 1)
DB2 FATAL ERROR for SQLExecute - Code: 40001/-911
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0911N  The current transaction has been rolled
back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".  SQLSTATE=40001
```

Tip: You can see about capabilities in awk about pattern matching here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Expression-Patterns.html

Comment: This works: awk '!/incompatible with type Alpha/' ladb.log  But why would this not work: awk '!/incompatible with type Alpha/ && /begin ibmdb error message/,/Reason code "68"/' ladb.log   For I it does not allow me to exclude when using the &&.  It returns the Alpha line.

Comment: @Configueroa Is the alpha line included in the range `/begin ibmdb error message/,/Reason code "68"/` ?

Comment: @Configueroa I suppose yes. You are mixing ranges of lines with and/not expressions that refer to records existed in the range. This will work : `awk '/begin ibmdb error message/,/Reason code "68"/{if ($0 !~ /type Alpha/) print}' file11`

Comment: @Configueroa Well?